# Converting possible null value to a default in a time conversion inside of Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given the timezone offset value as a nullable int how would I go about converting that inside the linq query to the current time of the location?

```
 var data = (from c in dbContext.Contacts
                      select new
                        {
                            c.Id,
                            TheirTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(c.TimezoneOffset)
                     })
```

This returns a "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddHours(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." error.

Comment: You might want to check the answer to my question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901025/custom-extension-method-to-simplify-linq-to-sql-statement).

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717177/how-to-query-and-calculate-dates-in-the-where-clause-of-a-linq-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this specific query:

```
var data = (from c in dbContext.Contacts
                      select new
                        {
                            c.Id,
                            TheirTime =EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow,c.TimezoneOffset)
                     })
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't familiar with those. But they have been deprecated and replaced with System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions

Comment: @JohnS I didn't know your entity framework version. But thanks for the info. Cool stuff!